# Button_Clicked Event manipulate a specific Element (pure C# (Page.cs))

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to create a lot of Labels and Buttons and to make this task easier and more dynamic I initialized these in a for loop in a pure C# Page (Page.cs).

How can I manipulate a specific Label with a Button_Clicked Event (in my case the Label with the index `i`, which has been created together with the Button in the for loop)?

Here is a summary of my problem:

```cs
// Constructor
public Page()
{
    Label[] lb = new Label[10];
    Button[] btn = new Button[lb.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < lb.Length; i++)
    {
        lb[i] = new Label();
        btn[i] = new Button();
        btn[i].Clicked += Button_Clicked; 
        // TODO Somehow reference the Label in the Button Clicked Method
    }

    // set Content ...
}
```

```cs
// Buton Clicked Method
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lb[i].Text = "Hello World!"; 
    // lb[i] should be the Label, which was initialized with the Button in the for loop
}
```

or is there a better way, to achieve my goal?

Comment: When working with Lambdas the index, with which the Button_Click Event is called, is the index which increased to the maximum of the for the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may manipulate a specific Label with a Button_Clicked Event by wrapping a pair of button and label into one `StackLayout` and adding a `ClassId` property to each `StackLayout`.

The sample code is like this:

```
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        Label[] lb;
        Button[] btn;
        StackLayout[] sl;
        int i = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            sl = new StackLayout[10];
            lb = new Label[10];
            btn = new Button[lb.Length];
            StackLayout content = new StackLayout();
            for (i = 0; i < lb.Length; i++)
            {
                lb[i] = new Label()
                {
                    Text = "Old Text"+i,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                };
                btn[i] = new Button
                {
                    Text = "Click to Change Label Text!"+i,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                };
                btn[i].Clicked += (sender, e) => Button_Clicked(sender, e);
                // TODO Somehow reference the Label in the Button Clicked Method
                sl[i] = new StackLayout
                {
                    ClassId = ""+i,
                    Children =
                    {
                        lb[i],
                        btn[i]
                    }
                };
                content.Children.Add(sl[i]);
            }
            Content = content;

        }
        // Buton Clicked Method
        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button bt = sender as Button;
            StackLayout layout = bt.Parent as StackLayout;
            int index = Int32.Parse(layout.ClassId);
            lb[index].Text = "Hello World!" + index;
        }
    }
```

The result is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 10 labels, I would just use lambdas.

```
Label[] lb = new Label[10];
Button[] btn = new Button[lb.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < lb.Length; i++)
{
    lb[i] = new Label();
    btn[i] = new Button();
    btn[i].Clicked += (s,e) => { lb[i].Text = "hello world" };
}
```

Comment: When I click the Button, the Method is called with the index being 9 (in my case). So when clicking the Button he sends the index, which already increased to the end of the loop.
And I'm getting the Error `System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to achieve this is to modify event handler during the registration.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lb.Length; i++)
    {
        lb[i] = new Label();
        btn[i] = new Button();
        btn[i].Clicked += (sender, e) => Button_Clicked(sender, e, i); 
        //Here i is to pass the index to event handler Button_Clicked; 
    }
```

And now, you could access index in button clicked event handler and you could access the label with the index passed.

Comment: When I click the Button, the Method is called with the index being 9 (in my case). So when clicking the Button he sends the index, which already increased to the end of the loop. And I'm getting the Error System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".